# Can anyone identify the Make and Model of this nosed-over plane?

Tags: general-aviation, aircraft-identification, single-engine

I've tried to identify this plane by the writing on the plate on the cowling but have been unable to match the logo, and when I've blown the size up the writing is unreadable. It looks something like SCOOTROM with a long tail on the upper part of the "S" and with two straight lines under it.  I think this light crash took place in Wisconsin, perhaps Madison or Stoughton but I don't have a year.[image]

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I believe this is a [Stinson HW-75 (Also called the 105 Voyager)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stinson_Voyager).

I know for sure this is a Stinson aircraft due to the logo which was often rendered on the side of aircraft with a double underline and certainly has the long tail on the upper part of the S as you described:

[image: Stinson logo]

[image: Logo from the original picture]

<sub>Logo from the orignal picture, rotated and de-skewed</sub>

The identifying features which make me think this is an HW-75/105 Voyager are:

- Similar decals down the side of the fueselage as shown in image below
- Twin Supports meeting at the main gear roots
- Shape of the step for access to the cockpit
- Grill both side and below the spinner

[image]
<sub>source: Wikimedia commons</sub>

However there is a slight chance that this is actually another Stinson model such as a [108](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stinson_108) or [L-5 Sentinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stinson_L-5_Sentinel) which both share some similarities

Comment: Damn it, you beat me to it :-)

Comment: @DeltaLima It had to happen eventually. I'm an amateur though - do you agree its a 105 and not a 108 or L-5? (And thanks for the improvement showing the logos side by side!)

Comment: I am pretty sure it is a 105. The 108 is very similar, but the decals on the side of the 108 were different. I have seen [pictures](https://twitter.com/CWHM/status/1242484522949763072/photo/1) of the 105 with exactly the same decals as the crashed aircraft.

Comment: No question it's a 105 in my opinion.  The straight leading edged, fabric-covered fin confirms it.  The 108 had the metal fin with the distinctive external ribs (corrugations). Also the stabilizer location is lower than the 108.  Also the nose bowl is from the 105. The 108 had a different grille arrangement and a box projection below for the airbox.  It's not an L-5 either; no greenhouse.  I thought the flipped one might have an Aeromatic prop, but the logo on the blade is wrong.  Possibly just a ground adjustable wood prop of some kind.

Comment: You guys blow me away.  I had done the same thing with the logo, blew it up and flipped it over, and my result looks the same as the one posted, I guess by Jamiec?  And seeing it next to that Stinson logo nails it as a Stinson.  I swear, I spent over an hour trying to identify this plane, as I do with all my photos, but at some point, I give up and come to you experts.  I'm amazed, and pleased, that so far every photo I've posted, you've come through for me.  Please know that I do try, and have been able to identify the planes in many of my other photos, but when I dead end, here I come. :-)

Comment: @FreshBreeze It's fun to try to identify them. I have to be honest I have no special ability other than I started looking at pictures of vintage monoplanes, looking specifically for that double strut, which is a fairly uncommon feature.  It was only after I found a few that looked likely that I back traced the logo. ie, I identified the plane by looking at pictures before I put 2 and 2 together to get the logo match.  It was DeltaLima who produced the deskewed image from your picture and matched it up with an image I had added to this question of the logo

Comment: @Jamiec, I did the same thing.  I even did a search of aircraft manufacturer logos. I'm just not very good at it. I'll type ten or more different descriptions of a plane and still come up empty.  Well, not always.  Actually, I've been able to identify at least half of the plane photos I'm going through.  But I get totally stuck and frustrated with the planes I post here and I'm extremely happy that you, DeltaLima, and a few others have so far been 100% successful in helping me.  I can't express how much I appreciate this.  When I get all my photos labeled I'm going to share a YouTube video.